# text overlapping in footer of website css/html formatting

Tags: css, text, footer

This is my first HTML/CSS project. I am attempting to re-construct Google's main page. I can't figure out how to get the right-hand text (Privacy & Terms Settings) on the footer to be correctly spaced out and not overlap. The project code is viewable on Github at https://github.com/msarnicki/google-homepage

The page can be previewed here: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/msarnicki/google-homepage/blob/master/index.html

I'd appreciate any tips, advice or links to related posts I seem to have missed.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't give us a link to the page, provide a minimal snippet that demonstrates the problem. Links break, making your question turn into nonsense; Examples will always be useful to others once your question has been answered. Plus, giving us a link assumes we'll chase down the needed information necessary to help you, but instead they tend to discourage people who would answer you, so help us help you.

Comment: Artjom - Thanks for your feedback; that makes perfect sense. I will be sure to format any future questions with snippets and/or Codepen/JSfiddle examples.

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsfiddle that might help you. http://jsfiddle.net/ZH55A/1/
I think the biggest problem you had was the fact that the two lists expanded the entire width of the footer. I changed the display of the lists and floated the #right list instead of the list items.

Here are the changes I made.

```
#left {
    display: inline-block;    
}

#right {
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;  
}

#right li {
    display: inline;
    text-align:right; 
    z-index: 99;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#left li {
    text-align:left;   
    display:inline; 
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thank you for the snippet and explanation. That makes complete sense and I see where I went wrong. Much thanks!